# Incomplete sentences

Tags: reference-request, linguistics, language-processing, speech, speech-comprehension

I am looking for studies which looks at understanding and preference of incomplete sentences.

For example, is there a higher workload for (in)complete sentences or even though the sentence might be fully understandable with the key information people might still prefer the complete sentence.

I am interested in this question for an verbal context but a written context would be great as well.